# How to automatically quote unquoted values in sql statements that would generate syntax errors

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a list of strings representing SQL statements such as:

```
select * from foo where name = sam smith;

select bar from foo where name = toni jade and town = south park;
```

I'd like to transform the string into an executable sql query.

```
select * from foo where name='sam smith';

select bar from foo where name ='toni jade' and town ='south park';
```

The strings in the list are all relatively simple but do not conform to a very small set of patterns.

Answer (score 2):

There is no theoretical solution to the problem you pose.  Any solution will be heuristic and will fail on some arbitrary inputs.

Consider part of your example,

> `where name = sam smith;`

An SQL parser would complain about *sam* because it's not a column name and not a (quoted) literal.  If you had access to an SQL parser — good luck with that! — you could use it to intervene, and gobble up successive unquoted strings after the `=` until it saw a new SQL token.  It would stop on `;`, and the logic could transform `sam smith` into `'sam smith'`.  Yay!

But what if `sam` *is* a column name?  Then the parser stumbles on *smith*, and your heuristic has to back up (I guess) to the assignment operator, assume the `sam` column isn't what what was intended, and that *'sam smith'* was.  Or, maybe the user meant `sam.smith`, referring to the `smith` column of the `sam` table....

From the point of view of language theory, your question illustrates that, for any language, there's an infinite number of syntactically incorrect inputs.   While it's possible to test whether an input obeys the language's syntax, and possible to identify where an input goes wrong, it's not possible to account for all the ways it could go wrong.  If it were, we wouldn't have compiler errors.  We'd have autocorrecting compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't your algorithm identify other parts of your query as strings that need to be quoted?

Like this:

```
select * from foo where 'name'='sam smith';
```

Or even this legal SQL statement (at least to SQLite):

```
select '* from foo where name=sam smith';
```

Ultimately, it's not possible for an algorithm to guess what you *intended* the code to be. It's not a good idea to rely on such an algorithm if it's bound to guess wrong in a substantial number of cases.

It's more economical and more accurate to just write your code the way you want it to work.

[image]

Source: https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/08/25/a-very-comprehensive-and-precise-spec/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a stored proc that would implement the required logic, dynamically generate your sql statements and then execute them